# Calculating Sum of column where values not present in a list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've initialized a list containing the following values:
`l = ['Umbrella', 'Umbrella'].`

I also have a dataframe with 4 columns. I would like to initiate a conditional IF/else statement in my loop ( which picking up 200 daily files in the directory ) whereby if Column A value is in the list then I would like it to perform a sum operation - and if it is not in the list to also perform a sum but save it in another variable.

My dataframe is as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'], 
               'Product':['Umbrella', 'Umbrella', 'Badminton', 'Shuttle'], 
               'Last Price':[1200, 1500, 1600, 352], 
               'Updated Price':[1250, 1450, 1550, 400], 
               'Discount':[10, 10, 10, 10]})
```

While performing the below code seems to work for the first file ( values correspond to the calculation performed ''by hand'' - the operation does not compute correctly for the ''Calibrated'' variable when the loop runs and computes for the other days.

```
Cumulative_Spend = df[df['Product'].isin(l)].groupby('Product')['Last Price'].sum() 
Calibrated = df[~df['Product'].isin(l)].groupby('Product')['Last Price'].tail(1)
```

Appreciate if someone could provide some guidance on why the Calibrated variable is not calculating correctly when looping the Calibrated calculation.

Comment: What is your desired output? It is unclear from your question. Why are you calling `tail(1)` if you are looking for a sum

Comment: You want the sum of "Badminton" and "Shuffle", right? not just the sum of one of these products? In that case you better not use group, but something like df.loc[~df['Product'].isin(l), 'Last Price'].sum()